# Sequential execution of multiple spark jobs in dataproc / gcp

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I would like to launch sequentially multiple spark jobs in gcp, like

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark file1.py
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark file2.py
...
```

so that the execution of one of those starts just when the execution of the previous job is completed.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using [Dataproc Workflows templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/using-workflows)

This workflow will create and delete the cluster as part of the workflow.

These are the steps you can follow to create the workflow:

1. Create your workflow template

```sh
export REGION=us-central1

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create workflow-id \
  --region $REGION
```

2. Set a Dataproc cluster type that will be used for the jobs

```sh
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster workflow-id \
    --region $REGION \ 
    --master-machine-type machine-type \ 
    --worker-machine-type machine-type \ 
    --num-workers number \ 
    --cluster-name cluster-name
```

3. Add the jobs as steps to your workflow

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark gs://bucket-name/file1.py \
    --region $REGION \ 
    --step-id job1 \ 
    --workflow-template workflow-id
```

The second job needs the parameter `--start-after` to make sure it runs after the first job.

```sh
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark gs://bucket-name/file2.py \
    --region $REGION \ 
    --step-id job2 \ 
    --start-after job1 \ 
    --workflow-template workflow-id
```

4. Run the workflow

```sh
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate template-id \
    --region $REGION \
```